# Correct notation for the CDF of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, notation

I have a random variable, $x$, distributed uniformly on $[0,\frac{4}{3}]$. The probability that $x$ is greater than some $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is, of course, given by $(1-0.75(a))$. I want the value of that expression to be constrained to $[0,1]$. Is the following the correct notation to use: $$\min\bigg\{\max\{1-0.75(a),0\},1\bigg\}$$ This way, if (1) $a>\frac{4}{3}$ , we get $0$. If (2) $a<0$, we get $1$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A more succinct notation for that is $((1-0.75a)\vee 0)\wedge 1$.

More generally, you can clamp $x$ to the interval $[a,b]$ by $(x\vee a)\wedge b$ (implicitly, $a\leq b$).

Answer (score 1):

Both OP's and MPW's options are correct, but I tend to find an explicit listing of the cases to be clearer—e.g.,

$$
F(a) = \begin{cases}
    0 & a < 0 \\
    1-\frac34a & 0 \leq a \leq \frac43 \\
    1 & a > \frac43
\end{cases}
$$